Chat template for any base model
I want to instruct fine tune the base pretrained llama3.1 model. But base model do not have chat template in Huggingface. So can I use chat template of my interest to fine tune the model for my downstream task? or it is advisable to use the chat template of the llama 3.1 instruct model to llama3.1 base model for fine tuning?
Can someone please clarify my doubt? I am little confused.
